# Find minimum of $ [ x^{(\ln y-\ln z)} + y^{(\ln z-\ln x )} + z^{(\ln x-\ln y)} ]$

Tags: logarithms, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

If $$x\gt0,y\gt 0, z\gt 0$$ then find the minimum value of
$$ \left[   x^{(\ln y-\ln z)} + y^{(\ln z-\ln x )} + z^{(\ln x-\ln y)}  \right]$$
Today I came across this question ( maybe it's from ***Progressions and Series*** )  and was unable to solve it , I tried in this way...
$$ a^{log_cb}=b^{log_ca}$$hence $$ \left[   x^{(\ln y-\ln z)} + y^{(\ln z-\ln x )} + z^{(\ln x-\ln y)}  \right]=\left[  \left({y\over z}\right)^{\ln x} +\left({z\over x}\right)^{\ln y} +\left({x\over y}\right)^{\ln z} \right] $$
now using property $AM \ge GM$ implies $$\left[   x^{(\ln y-\ln z)} + y^{(\ln z-\ln x )} + z^{(\ln x-\ln y)}  \right]\ge \sqrt[3]{y^{\ln {x\over z}}z^{\ln {y\over x}}x^{\ln {z\over y}}} $$ but i cann't get any further .Is the question wrong? Is the approach wrong? Looking for some hints to get started...

Comment: What do the square brackets mean here?

Comment: @HenningMakholm they are just simple brackets

Comment: x @Subhajit: \*sigh\* What do the "simple brackets" mean here?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sir, they don't mean anything . ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: There's no reason to be rude. Goodbye.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sir , I am sorry if I said anything wrong. And I always denote anyone by Sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83466/discussion-between-subhajit-halder-and-henning-makholm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given expression can be rewritten as

$$\frac{x^{ln\left(y\right)}}{x^{ln\left(z\right)}}+\frac{y^{ln\left(z\right)}}{y^{ln\left(x\right)}}+\frac{z^{ln\left(x\right)}}{z^{ln\left(y\right)}}$$

Apply A.M >= G.M.

$$\left(\frac{\frac{x^{ln\left(y\right)}}{x^{ln\left(z\right)}}+\frac{y^{ln\left(z\right)}}{y^{ln\left(x\right)}}+\frac{z^{ln\left(x\right)}}{z^{ln\left(y\right)}}}{3}\right)\ge \left(\frac{x^{ln\left(y\right)}}{x^{ln\left(z\right)}}\cdot \frac{y^{ln\left(z\right)}}{y^{ln\left(x\right)}}\cdot \frac{z^{ln\left(x\right)}}{z^{ln\left(y\right)}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

Using $a^{\log _c\left(b\right)}=b^{log_c\left(a\right)}$ , the denominators on the right side of the inequality can be manipulated.

$$\left(\frac{\frac{x^{ln\left(y\right)}}{x^{ln\left(z\right)}}+\frac{y^{ln\left(z\right)}}{y^{ln\left(x\right)}}+\frac{z^{ln\left(x\right)}}{z^{ln\left(y\right)}}}{3}\right)\ge \:\left(\frac{x^{ln\left(y\right)}}{z^{ln\left(x\right)}}\cdot \:\frac{y^{ln\left(z\right)}}{x^{ln\left(y\right)}}\cdot \:\frac{z^{ln\left(x\right)}}{y^{ln\left(z\right)}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

$$\left(\frac{\frac{x^{ln\left(y\right)}}{x^{ln\left(z\right)}}+\frac{y^{ln\left(z\right)}}{y^{ln\left(x\right)}}+\frac{z^{ln\left(x\right)}}{z^{ln\left(y\right)}}}{3}\right)\ge \:\left(1\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

$$\left(\frac{x^{ln\left(y\right)}}{x^{ln\left(z\right)}}+\frac{y^{ln\left(z\right)}}{y^{ln\left(x\right)}}+\frac{z^{ln\left(x\right)}}{z^{ln\left(y\right)}}\right)\ge \:\left(3\right)$$

Therefore the minimum value of the expression is 3.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$x=e^u \quad y=e^v \quad z=e^w \quad u,v,w\in \mathbb{R}$$

then

$$ x^{(\ln y-\ln z)} + y^{(\ln z-\ln x )} + z^{(\ln x-\ln y)} = \frac{e^{uv}}{e^{uw}}+\frac{e^{vw}}{e^{uv}}+\frac{e^{uw}}{e^{vw}}\ge 3$$

by AM-GM or more directly by [Rearrangement inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Rearrangement_Inequality).

Comment: Right after your second step, you can use AM-GM to get the minimum of 3, is it not?

Comment: Yes of course both are good method! I add that, Thanks. Bye